# Android: What should I use when making a native video player?

Tags: android, c++, video, android-ndk, ffmpeg

Currently I am doing research for a native video player project, initialy I tried to use ffmpeg as the decoder and return the Byte to java, then I use View::onDraw with Canvas to display frames. Unfortunately, the performance of this method is not good, so I am wondering whether there is anything else that I could use to display frames other then passing to java?

Also, other than display the frames, how can I play sound using C/C++ with NDK?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ffmpeg http://ffmpeg.org and/or libtheora http://www.theora.org to decode video frames. Then just display the result via OpenGL ES 2 using render-to-texture. Refer to http://www.gamedev.net/topic/570295-opengl-and-xvidtheoraanything for details.

For audio you can use OpenAL. Here is the Android port: http://pielot.org/2010/12/14/openal-on-android

Comment: It seems really helpful,@Sergey can you plz suggest me how to get started with FFMpeg video decoding Thanks